# Understanding the time_t calls

Tags: c

I've written the following to print the local time as a string:

```
 char time_buffer[25];
 time_t t = time(&t);
 strftime(time_buffer, 25, "%c", localtime(&t));
 printf("Formatted time: %s\n", time_buffer);
```

However, the code doesn't make too much sense to me (even though I've written it). A few questions on it:

- How does `time_t t = time(&t)` work? Is this setting up a struct of the localtime? Where is it grabbing the time from?
- What is the difference between the `time(&t)` and `localtime(&t)`? Why are both needed?

Comment: There should be ample documentation on these functions, either from your implementation or from the C standard.  What have you checked already, and what part are you confused about?

Comment: Also, why did you "write" this, if it doesn't make sense?

Comment: The use of `time_t t = time(&t);` is a little odd, but safe enough.  It would be as sensible to pass a null pointer to the function — `time_t t = time(NULL);` or even just `time_t t = time(0);`.  That way, `t` is not set twice — but the double setting is safe because of the rules about sequence points (the assignment in the `time()` function must be complete before the function returns, so the second assignment after the function returns is safe).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`time()` is implemented in libc.  For example, here is the implementation in glibc 2.33 for Linux:

```
time (time_t *t)
{
  return INLINE_VSYSCALL (time, 1, t);
}
```

which asks the kernel via a syscall for the time. The kernel, in turn, maintains a variable somewhere with this information. The kernel gets the time on boot from a battery backed clock and often subsequently sync'ed with a reference clock source (on Linux this would be via the Network Time Protocol (NTP)).

`time()` returns a time_t (on my system that is a typedef of long) which is number of seconds since epoch (this is measure of time is independent of timezone).  `localtime()` returns a `struct tm *` which has the usual components for of date and time (sec, min, hour, day, month, year etc) in whatever timezone you selected (on Linux via the environment variable TZ).

Comment: Note that `localtime()` returns a `struct tm *` (a pointer to a static structure; it is not thread-safe). There's [`localtime_r()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/localtime_r.html) on POSIX systems. In theory, the functions from C11 ([Annex K.3.8 Date and time `<time.h>`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.8) provides functions such as `localtime_s()` that are roughly equivalent; the Microsoft versions of those would be available on Windows. I haven't checked to see whether there are significant differences between Annex K and Microsoft for those functions.